# How can i extract parameter from http requests with Qt?

Tags: qt, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

i have a qt application and i want to run it on an nginx server. I already figured out how to configure the server to call c++ applications as fastcgi: [Nginx Fastcgi c++](http://chriswu.me/blog/writing-hello-world-in-fcgi-with-c-plus-plus/). But i don't know how qt will handle the http request data. I am looking for something similiar to php [$_GET and $_POST](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.request.php). It can extract data from the incomming http request and then generate an answer that goes back to the client.

Question: **What kind of Qt class or global variable represents the incomming request?** OR How can i access request parameter with qt?

Thank you.

Comment: Qt doesn't have such classes. It designed only to making requests, but not for handling them (there are no official Qt servers).

Comment: I learned that my webserver nginx can [set](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_param) environmental parameters that the fastcgi programm can read.... but how can qt read those?

Comment: You can read parameters with fastcgi

Comment: I came across [qgetenv()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv). It reads environmental variables hence cgi parameters...